# Regular expression is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm trying to write a regex to allow phone country codes in this format: `+NNNN`, where `N` is a number. I tried with this one but it didn't work:

```
/^\\+|[0-9]+$/
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I think its allowing more than 4 numbers. What about `/^\\+[0-9]{4}$/` ?

Comment: Well, it's JavaScript so obviously this wouldn't work due to the improper escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that?

```
/^\+[0-9]{1,4}$/
```

Comment: Won't this match `+9` or `+99`, which is not what the OP asks?

Comment: I have a extra problem, I should allow `+NNNN` but also `NNNNN` in this way only the first one is allowed, how I can fix that? I tough for that reason I had the `|` pipe

Comment: To allow '+' being optional, add a '?' symbol after the plus sign: /^\+?[0-9]{1,4}$/

Comment: Also, the pipe symbol is used to match between several alternatives, but I don't think this is going to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use pipe inside your regex. Just remove it. Using pipe actually bisecting your regex into two.

```
/^\\+[0-9]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `/^\+[0-9]{4}$/`

Matches: `+9999`

1. `\+` matches `+` literally.
2. `[0-9]{4}` matches 4 occurrences of a digit.